# Str split only on specific place

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, split

Hi how could I split on a dot after a number and generate just two columns to the original df?

```
df.name
 ``         
0    1. The start
1    2. Today's world
2    3. Today's world vs. yesterday.
...
20   20. The change
```

Expected Output:

```
     number   title
0     1       The start
1     2       Today's world
2     3       Today's world vs. yesterday.
...
20    20      The change
```

I tried

```
df[['number', 'title']] = df.name.str.split('(\d+.)', expand=True)
```

Comment: `str.split` doesn't support regex. Instead do `split('.',1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for split by integers before `.` and another values:

```
df[['number', 'title']] = df.name.str.extract('(^\d+)\.\s+(.*)')

print (df)
                               name number                          title
0                      1. The start      1                      The start
1                  2. Today's world      2                  Today's world
2   3. Today's world vs. yesterday.      3   Today's world vs. yesterday.
20                   20. The change     20                     The change
```

Comment: You may also want to consider a pattern like `'(^\d+)\.\s+(.*)'` To remove any of the leading spaces before the title.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use zero length assertion and escape `.` as it has special meaning in regular expressions pattern i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["1. The start","2. Today's world","3. Today's world vs. yesterday."]})
df[['number', 'title']] = df.name.str.split(r'(?<=\d)\.', expand=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                              name number                          title
0                     1. The start      1                      The start
1                 2. Today's world      2                  Today's world
2  3. Today's world vs. yesterday.      3   Today's world vs. yesterday.
```